# How to completely remove python2.4 and update to 2.7

Tags: linux, centos, python

I have installed python 2.7 but if I use python on shell then python 2.4 opens.
Also, I installed the MySQL module and it gets installed for python 2.4.

I don't want this to happen, can I make it that everything links to python 2.7, not 2.4?

Comment: This belongs more on Superuser.com??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't remove 2.4, since doing so will damage your system. Invoke `python2.7` instead.

Comment: i tried it didn't worked, i have to use `/opt/python27/bin/python`

Comment: I've seen you question has been answered, good. For future reference you could use the command (on UNIX/Linux based OSes) `whereis` to find the binary path of a command in you $PATH or simply `sudo find / -name "python2.7"` to search your whole system for matching files.

Answer (score 0):

Any case, you have to set the default python to point to your python2.7 installation. which python will give you something like /usr/bin/python. mv it to a backup and create a softlink in that folder to your python2.7 executable.

P.S: Guessing you are using CentOS, using python2.7 expect yum to fail and also a lot of other tools.